# How to count lines based on font styles in range of cells in Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a range of cells in an Excel document that look like this:

[image: Example Excel cells]

I want to write a function that goes through and counts how many lines across all the cells in a selection are NOT italicized. For example, this should return 3 (things 1, 3, and 4). I know very little about Excel and VBA but I have put together this script so far:

```
Function CountNonItalic(Sel As Range)
    Count = 0

    For Each Cell In Sel
        CellVals = Split(Cell.Value, Chr(10))    'Chr(10) = ASCII \n in UNIX
        For Each Line In CellVals
            If Line.Font.Italic = True Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next Line
    Next Cell

    CountNonItalic = Count
End Function
```

However, this is not working and I think it is because the `Split()` function splits the cell into strings, which gets rid of the font and fontstyle data. Is there another good way that I can do this?

Comment: You'll need to loop over the `Characters` collection for each cell and check the `Font.Italic` property.  Will there be any lines with mixed italic formatting, or will each line have a consistent style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop over sections of each cell's `Characters` collection and check the `Font.Italic` property.

Try this out:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print NonItalicLines([A1])
End Sub

Function NonItalicLines(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim c As Range, arr, posStart As Long, line, length, res As Long, i As Long, ital
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        arr = Split(c.Value, vbLf)
        posStart = 1
        i = 0
        For Each line In arr
            i = i + 1
            length = Len(line)
            If length > 0 Then 'only check lines with content
                ital = c.Characters(posStart, length).Font.Italic
                Debug.Print c.Address, "Line " & i, "italic=" & ital
                If Not ital Then res = res + 1
            End If
            posStart = posStart + length + 1 ' +1 for the vbLf
        Next line
    Next c
    NonItalicLines = res
End Function
```

Note that for a range of more than one character, if the italics are not consistent, then you'll get `Null` instead of `True` or `False` when reading `Font.Italic`.   You'd need to decide whether that counts the line as italic or non-italic.